# How can I find out what argument was given to a mocked method?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mockito

If I write something like this:

```
verify().that( mockPromise.handleFault( any() ))
```

it works fine to tell me that 'handleFault' was invoked.

But later I want to invoke the fault handler function that was passed in. The handler will be a private function so there isn't another way to access it.

Comment: The only documentation I can find is https://bitbucket.org/loomis/mockito-flex/wiki/Home, which doesn't have much. So maybe I'm missing something there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java Mockito, the feature you're looking for is called `ArgumentCaptor`. In short, it's a special kind of `Matcher` (like `any()`) that matches any type of object and keeps the object it "matches" in a variable.

Unfortunately, it looks like it's [not available in Flex yet](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mockito-flex/OS4YQjmIhAM).

The good news is that if you feel like it, you can probably write an implementation of the `Matcher` interface that does exactly that--save its most recent value and return true--in fifteen minutes or so. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I was coming to that conclusion. It seemed pretty ugly to do that but actually it's not so bad.

Comment: Also, I can't access google groups from within my company, so that could be why I can't find anything.

I added my solution below, based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jeff's answer, I did this:

```
import org.mockito.api.Matcher;

class ArgumentCaptor implements Matcher
{


    private var _value:*;


    public function ArgumentCaptor()
    {
    }

    public function get value():*
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public function describe():String
    {
        return "";
    }

    public function matches(value:*):Boolean
    {
        _value = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

which can be used like:

```
var argCaptor:ArgumentCaptor = new ArgumentCaptor();
verify().that( mockPromise.handleFault( argThat(argCaptor) ));

argCaptor.value; // the argument
```

Comment: If you are thinking about submitting this solution back to the project, you might want to make the API and semantics match the Mockito ArgumentCaptor a little more closely.

Comment: No, I don't think I can contribute this back. I looked at the Java implementation too, but it relies on a lot of code that just isn't written in the Flex version, so it would mean taking on a lot of work.